# Issue with sendto function and OS X sandbox

Tags: objective-c, macos

My OS X App it's ok and usually it send same icmp packets with the sendto C function:

```
ssize_t ssizet = sendto(icmp_socket, &icmp, sizeof(icmp), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sa)); 
if( ssizet==-1 )
{
NSLog(@"sendto error %s %d", strerror(errno), errno);
return;
}
```

Now i have activated the sandbox with this entitlements:

```
App Sandbox

com.apple.security.network.client

com.apple.security.network.server
```

The issue is that now (with sandbox activated) the `sendto` function fails with a "not operation permitted" error.

In console I have found a lot of messages like this:

> 24/03/16 20:44:05,340 sandboxd[115]: ([9013]) myPing(9013) deny network-outbound

So the problem is that the sandbox denies my `sendto` execution. But why?

I have configured the capabilities as I have show before. What's my error?